# iPad tab bar application needs to support both portrait orientations

Tags: ipad, orientation

Is there an easy way to set my application so that it can automatically rotate to only the portrait modes (no landscape)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - I had not set the autorotation delegate in all of my view controllers